# Loading CMS blocks with 'status' set to 'disabled'

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block

Trying to load a block for a store

`$cms_block = Mage::getModel('cms/‌​block')->setStoreId($‌​storeId)->load($block‌​);`

and printing it I obtain two different arrays.

If the block is `enabled` the result is an array full of informations ([block_id], [title], [is_active] etc.)

```
Mage_Cms_Model_Block Object
(
    [_cacheTag:protected] => cms_block
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
    [_eventObject:protected] => object
    [_resourceName:protected] => cms/block
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => cms/block_collection
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [block_id] => 214
            [title] => Home slide 1 - ES
            [identifier] => block_slide1
            [content] => <a href="{{store url='about-magento-demo-store'}}">

    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/promo-homepage/slide1-fr.jpg"}}" alt="" />

</a>
            [creation_time] => 2016-08-17 08:41:53
            [update_time] => 2016-08-17 13:33:04
            [is_active] => 1
            [store_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )

            [stores] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )

        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [block_id] => 214
            [title] => Home slide 1 - ES
            [identifier] => block_slide1
            [content] => <a href="{{store url='about-magento-demo-store'}}">

    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/promo-homepage/slide1-fr.jpg"}}" alt="" />

</a>
            [creation_time] => 2016-08-17 08:41:53
            [update_time] => 2016-08-17 13:33:04
            [is_active] => 1
            [store_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )

            [stores] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )

        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => block_id
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

but if the block is *disabled* these data are not available:

```
Mage_Cms_Model_Block Object
(
    [_cacheTag:protected] => cms_block
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
    [_eventObject:protected] => object
    [_resourceName:protected] => cms/block
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => cms/block_collection
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 1
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 1
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => block_id
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

So, how can I load the info for a disabled CMS blocks?

I need to set them to *enabled* status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried and tested, this should do the trick. Change store ID, block code, and the on/off switch as needed.

```
<?php

$storeId     = 1; // change store ID as appropriate
$blockCode   = 'home-decor'; // change to match your block's identifier code
$onOffSwitch = 0; // want to make block active or inactive?

/** @var Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Block_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
$collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
$collection->addFieldToFilter('identifier',$blockCode);

$block = $collection->getFirstItem();
if($id = $block->getId()){
    $block->load($id);
    $block->setData('is_active', $onOffSwitch);
    $block->save();
}
```

**Alternative solution:**

```
<?php 

$storeId     = 1; // change store ID as appropriate
$blockCode   = 'home-decor'; // change to match your block's identifier code
$onOffSwitch = 0; // want to make block active or inactive?

/** @var Mage_Cms_Model_Block $model */
$model    = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
$resource = $model->getResource();
$table    = $resource->getMainTable();
$idField  = $resource->getIdFieldName();

$adapter  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

/** @var Varien_Db_Select $select */
$select = $adapter->select()->from(array('main_table' => $table), $idField);
$select->join(array('store_table' => $adapter->getTableName('cms_block_store')), "main_table.{$idField} = store_table.{$idField}");
$select->where('main_table.identifier = ?', $blockCode);
$select->where('store_table.store_id = ?', $storeId);
if($id = $adapter->fetchOne($select)) {
    $adapter->update($table, array('is_active' => $onOffSwitch), array("{$idField} = ?" => $id));
}
```

**Additionally**, rather than using Mage::log() to see the output of your query, do this instead, as it will show you the final queries after all pieces have been put together.

Go to lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php and set the following properties to true.

```
protected $_debug = false; //change to true
protected $_logAllQueries = false; //change to true
```

All queries that take place will be logged in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`.

**In response to your initial question**, it seems that you are not loading the block, or at least properly, because there is no valid reason that it would show less info for a disabled block. I just tested the return data for a block, both enabled and disabled and here are the results.

[image]

[image]

The info in my screenshots was obtained by using the snippet below.

```
$blockId = 35;
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockId);
```

I should also mention, that when looping through a collection and doing `$block->getData()` you are not going to see all the data because the object is not fully loaded. You either have to use `$collection->addFieldToSelect('*')` or load the block within your loop. It is MUCH more efficient to add your fields to the select statement but you may have to join the `cms_block_store` table to get all data.

Comment: I've already developed a snippet like your.
The only difference is `addStoreFilter($storeId);` .. I don't know why it doesn't add store filter to the query; I've debugged it.
So I replace it with this code: 
`$cms_blocks = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addFieldTo‌​Filter('identifier', array('eq' => $my_identifier)); $select = $cms_blocks->getSelect()->join(array('block_store' => $cms_blocks->getTable('cms/block_store')), 'main_table.block_id = block_store.block_id', array('store_id'))->where('block_store.store_id IN (?)', array($storeId));`

Comment: Did you try my snippet unmodified? Works like a charm whether activating or deactivating

Comment: Yes, I did. I have the issue above described.
I'm using my solution (see below).

Comment: Just a thought. Are you debugging by letting the code run fully or are you stopping the code and echoing getSelect()?

Comment: @WaPoNe The reason I ask is because if your method of debugging is simply to `echo $collection->getSelect();` you will not see the store filter there. The filter gets added after the collection is loaded. If you `echo $collection->load()->getSelect();` then you will see your store filter.

Comment: after collection loading, `Mage::log('Query: '.$cms_blocks->getSelect(), null, 'mylog.log');`

Comment: Thats the problem. Change it to `Mage::log('Query: '.$cms_blocks->load()->getSelect(), null, 'mylog.log');`

Comment: @WaPoNe I just updated my answer with a fully tested alternative solution.

Comment: You're right. Now, after loading collection, in the query I find store filter:
`SELECT 'main_table'.* FROM 'cms_block' AS 'main_table'
 INNER JOIN 'cms_block_store' AS 'store_table' ON main_table.block_id = store_table.block_id WHERE ('identifier' = 'my_block_identifier') AND (store_table.store_id IN(5, 0)) GROUP BY 'main_table'.'block_id'`

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. I can only imagine you were going nuts wondering why it wasn't showing up in your query. Would you be so kind as to accept my answer? I have fully tested both the main solution and alternative and both work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is useful (I marked it) but the initial question remains without an answer

Comment: @WaPoNe I also just updated the answer to give you a better way to log your queries in the future. It will help you avoid the situation where filters aren't showing up.

Comment: @WaPoNe updated answer with answer to your initial question

Answer (score 2):

This is due to `->setStoreId($‌​storeId)` filter.

Just use `$cms_block = Mage::getModel('cms/‌​block')->load($block‌​);` to load CMS block.

You don't need to filter CMS model by store_id because all CMS blocks will have different IDs saved per store.

**UPDATE**: To save/update CMS block use :

```
//This will set CMS block Status to Enabled
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block)->setData('is_active', 1)->save();
```

Comment: I need to specify the store because I have same block identifier for my all four store and I want to set on (enable) only for one store.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to SAVE your block (per store) OR you want to show/load the data (per store) event if it's disabled ?

Comment: I want to SAVE its 'status' (is_active = 1) to enable it.

Comment: for that you don't need to filter cms model by store id because all cms block will have different IDs saved per store. CHECK updated answer

Comment: I know all cms block have different ID but they have the same identifier.
If I try to disable some (**enabled**) block using this method `Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($block)->setData('is_active', 0)->save();` all works fine but if I try to enable some (**disabled**) block using the same method it doesn't work because it doesn't load the block info.

Comment: You are not getting what I'm saying. Just don't use `setStoreId(‌​$storeId)` filter while saving/updating

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I know it works without `setStoreId(‌​$store‌​Id)` but I ask you how can I specify the exact block to enable?

I have four blocks that are disabled with the same identifier, one per stores.
How should I do to enable only the "Italian" block (for example) having block identifier? Is this possible?

Comment: @WaPoNe You have to call the collection of your blocks filtered by identifier AND store id. From that collection, you can derive the actual block id. Then pass that block id into your call to `load($blockId)`

Comment: I solved in this way, as @ShawnAbramson recommends:
`$cms_blocks = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('eq' => $my_identifier));
$select = $cms_blocks->getSelect()->join(array('block_store' => $cms_blocks->getTable('cms/block_store')), 'main_table.block_id = block_store.block_id', array('store_id'))->where('block_store.store_id IN (?)', array($storeId));
$blockId = $cms_blocks->getFirstItem()->getBlockId();
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockId)->setData('is_active', 1)->save();`

But my question remains without an answer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
$cms_blocks = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('eq' => trim($your_identifier)));
 $select = $cms_blocks->getSelect()
    ->join(array('block_store' => $cms_blocks->getTable('cms/block_store')), 'main_table.block_id = block_store.block_id', array('store_id'))
    ->where('block_store.store_id IN (?)', array($storeId));

$blockId = $cms_blocks->getFirstItem()->getBlockId();

 // Block enabling
 Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockId)->setData('is_active', 1)->save();
```